# SQL list all apartments with actual owner

Tags: sql, openedge, progress-db

I'm trying to use a query to list all apartments with actual owner.

My apartment table look like this:

```
building | apartmentNbr | owner |      start |        end
      b1 |           a1 |    o1 | 2009-08-13 | 2010-08-13
      b1 |           a1 |    o2 | 2010-08-14 | 2019-01-01
      b1 |           a2 |    o3 | 2009-01-03 | 2010-01-03
      b1 |           a2 |    o4 | 2010-01-04 | 2010-08-13
      b1 |           a2 |    o5 | 2010-08-14 | 9999-12-31
      b1 |           a3 |    o6 | 2010-08-14 | 2019-12-31
      b1 |           a3 |    o7 | 2020-02-14 | 9999-12-31
      b2 |           b1 |    o8 | 2012-08-14 | 9999-12-31
...
```

With my query

```
SELECT *
FROM Appartments
WHERE CURDATE() BETWEEN startDate AND endDate
```

I only have the occupied apartments but I would like to have also free like this:

```
building | apartmentNbr | owner
      b1 |           a1 |  null
      b1 |           a2 |    o5
      b1 |           a3 |  null
      b2 |           b1 |    o8
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Please tag your question with the database that you are using.

Comment: Are you using MySQL ?

Comment: I m using ODBC to connect to a Progress database

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do a `GROUP BY`. Use a `case` expression to get the current owner (or null).

```
SELECT building, apartmentNbr,
       max(case when CURDATE() BETWEEN startDate AND endDate then owner end)
FROM Appartments
GROUP BY building, apartmentNbr
```

Comment: If i want to get the dates, i have to add more CASE ?

Comment: Yes, you can. Or do a self join.